# How do we find the equation for the gyrating motion of a particle in a uniform magnetic field and a non-uniform Electric field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, computational-physics, plasma-physics, differential-equations, non-linear-systems

Considering the gyrating motion is not negligible and also retaining the guiding center drift, how do we get the trajectories x(t),y(t),z(t) of the particle?

In this case is the variation in the Larmor frequency and Larmor radius significant enough to consider them as variables.

How would the particle behave if they were considered as constants ?

$E(x)=E_0 x$, for some $E_0$ and $B = B_0$ for some constant Bo.

I came across the following differential equation while solving for the trajectory of a particle in a non-uniform electric and uniform magnetic field.

$$x'''+x''+xx' = 0, \quad x' = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}.$$

I chose the constants such as to get a simpler differential equation.

All the standard textbooks on Plasma Physics seem to skip over this part and only consider the guiding center drift.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95594/discussion-on-question-by-manoj-how-would-a-charged-particle-behave-in-a-uniform).

Comment: These edits as far as I can tell essentially invalidate the posted answer.  It's generally not a good idea to edit the question in a way that makes already posted answers invalid.

Comment: Please do not edit questions in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Comment: @ACuriousMind ok . Noted

Answer (score 6):

The equation can be integrated once, then we have second order equation
$$x''+x'+\frac {x^2}{2}=C_1$$
Make a substitution $x'=y(x)$, then $x''=y\frac {dy}{dx}$ as a result, we obtain the [Abel equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation_of_the_first_kind) , for which an analytical solution is known, see https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2011/387429/#sec2
$$y\frac {dy}{dx}+y=C_1-x^2/2$$
The numerical solution of the original equation depends on the boundary conditions. We can put the initial data as follows $x(0)=x_0,x'(0)=v_0,x''(0)=0$. Figure 1 shows the solution of the equation when changing $x_0$ (left) and $v_0$ (right)
[image: Figure 1]

Comment: what do you mean by $y[x]$?

Comment: I don't understand how you get your second equation from your first equation. I suspect the second equation is wrong. I believe $x'$ is a derivative with respect to some variable $t$, not $x$.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform This is a standard trick, you are trying to find $x'$ as a function of $x$. Alex is denoting this function by $y[x]$. Once $y$ is found, you solve the equation $x'=y[x]$ by standard methods.

Comment: @akhmeteli, it is not wrong. Take $t$ derivative of the substitution, use the substitution again.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk Thanks. Alex is a user of Mathematica, where brackets denote function evaluation, so I wasnt sure he meant $y[x]=y(x)$, or perhaps $y[x]=xy(x)$. Anyway, it might be useful to clarify the notation in the OP.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Sorry, I corrected typos and added a numerical solution.

Comment: @AlexTrounev How did you get the numerical solution?

Comment: @Manoj I use Mathematica 12. I can publish the code.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Oh, what is the underlying numerical method? Like Runge-Kutta4 etc. Also, this equation's form does not seem to match with the one in the link you provided. This appears to be of Abel's second kind but does it have an analytic solution?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Heads up, this question has been going through some major edits.

Comment: @Manoj A combination of methods is used. If you have a specific method, I can check how it works. See the transformation of the Abel equation with $f_0=f_1=0,f_2=1,f_3=C_1-x^2/2$ to the canonical form on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation_of_the_first_kind